# Is there a way to stop multi thread tests for don't interfere in each other in the database side?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, testing

I'm implementing tests for a multithreaded microservice, and I'm afraid that the tests that make checks in the database do not interfere with each other, do exites a way?

The tests are mos of them like that:

`@Test
    @Transactional
    public void createRefillOfferEvent() throws Exception {
        int databaseSizeBeforeCreate = refillOfferEventRepository.findAll().size();`

```
   // Create the RefillOfferEvent
    RefillOfferEventDTO refillOfferEventDTO = refillOfferEventMapper.toDto(refillOfferEvent);
    restRefillOfferEventMockMvc.perform(post("/api/refill-offer-events")
        .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
        .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(refillOfferEventDTO)))
        .andExpect(status().isCreated());

    // Validate the RefillOfferEvent in the database
    List<RefillOfferEvent> refillOfferEventList = refillOfferEventRepository.findAll();
    assertThat(refillOfferEventList).hasSize(databaseSizeBeforeCreate + 1);
    RefillOfferEvent testRefillOfferEvent = refillOfferEventList.get(refillOfferEventList.size() - 1);
    //assertThat(testRefillOfferEvent.getRequestDate()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_REQUEST_DATE);
    assertThat(testRefillOfferEvent.getRequesttransactionid()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_REQUESTTRANSACTIONID);
    assertThat(testRefillOfferEvent.getMsisdn()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_MSISDN);
    assertThat(testRefillOfferEvent.getPlatform()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_PLATFORM);
    assertThat(testRefillOfferEvent.getOfferId()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_OFFER_ID);
    assertThat(testRefillOfferEvent.getOfferName()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_OFFER_NAME);
    assertThat(testRefillOfferEvent.getOfferAmount()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_OFFER_AMOUNT);
    assertThat(testRefillOfferEvent.getOfferProfileId()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_OFFER_PROFILE_ID);
    assertThat(testRefillOfferEvent.getResponseStatus()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_RESPONSE_STATUS);
    assertThat(testRefillOfferEvent.getResponseCode()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_RESPONSE_CODE);
    assertThat(testRefillOfferEvent.getResponseDescription()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_RESPONSE_DESCRIPTION);
    assertThat(testRefillOfferEvent.getInfo1()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_INFO_1);
    assertThat(testRefillOfferEvent.getInfo2()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_INFO_2);
    assertThat(testRefillOfferEvent.getInfo3()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_INFO_3);
    assertThat(testRefillOfferEvent.getInfo4()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_INFO_4);
    assertThat(testRefillOfferEvent.getInfo5()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_INFO_5);

    // Validate the RefillOfferEvent in Elasticsearch
    RefillOfferEvent refillOfferEventEs = refillOfferEventSearchRepository.findOne(testRefillOfferEvent.getId());
    assertThat(refillOfferEventEs).isEqualToIgnoringGivenFields(testRefillOfferEvent);
}`
```

That's what i get

Failed tests:
  RefillOfferEventResourceIntTest.deleteRefillOfferEvent:394
Expected size:<6> but was:<7> in: